# grub2-mkconfig doesn't show Windows

Tags: fedora, windows, grub2, grub

After recently having installed Fedora on the same HDD as Windows, Boot manager no longer shows up in Grub2. When trying to repair what I've done by running grub2-mkconfig, it doesn't find Windows. Nor can I find the EFI file when I launch.

I don't know what to do next nor what information is needed to troubleshoot.

I tried to use the Ubuntu Boot Repair http://paste.ubuntu.com/14403239

fdisk gives:

```
Device         Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    1333247   1331200   650M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2    1333248    1742847    409600   200M EFI System
/dev/sda3    1865728    2127871    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4    2127872  783116460 780988589 372.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  965017600 1000204287  35186688  16.8G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6  783118336  784142335   1024000   500M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda7  931614720  965017599  33402880    16G Linux swap
/dev/sda8  898211840  931614719  33402880    16G Linux swap
/dev/sda9  784142336  817770495  33628160    16G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda10 817770496  829335551  11565056   5.5G Linux swap
/dev/sda11 829335552  898211839  68876288  32.9G Linux filesystem
```

Comment: What gives you the command `fdisk -l /dev/yourdisk`?

Comment: I've updated the question